# How to theme the header area using panels everywhere and twitter bootstrap theme?

Tags: panels, bootstrapping

I am using panels everywhere and I am using the twitter bootstrap theme and  panels bootstrap layouts. At the moment I have the 'header elements' from 'page elements' menu pane which contains the site name, logo and slogan and can be themed with pane_header.tpl.php . However, I would also like to include the menu in this because I need to wrap all these elements in the bootstrap menu html in order to use the collapsing navbar functionality?